# creating sales order with new items in Suitescript 2.0

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am writing suitescript 2.0 with Map/Reduce type.
I am fetching some list orders through API, I check for customer, if exist then create order otherwise first create customer and then add sales order with its items (which are new items). I am getting an error of `You have entered an Invalid Field Value 5260365201455 for the following field: item`.
I am assuming (as I am new with suitescript), that while creating sales order following script will create its items too.

**CODE** -- UPDATED as per below answer

```
// updated function for creating item
    function createChildItems(itemName) {
        log.debug({ title: 'createChildItems', details: 'child item' });

        var item = record.create({
            type: record.Type.INVENTORY_ITEM,
            isDynamic: true
        });
        item.setValue({ fieldId: 'itemid', value:itemName });
        var itemId = item.save({
            ignoreMandatoryFields: true
        });
        return itemId;
    }
```

this above functions creates the item and return its internal id,

```
var salesOrder = record.create({
    type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER,
    isDynamic: true,
    defaultValues: {
        entity: customer.id
    }
});

salesOrder.setValue({ fieldId: 'trandate', value: new Date(), ignoreFieldChange: true });

var subrec = salesOrder.getSubrecord({
    fieldId: 'shippingaddress'
});

subrec.setValue({ fieldId: 'addr1', value: order.shipping_address.address1 });
subrec.setValue({ fieldId: 'city', value: order.shipping_address.city });
subrec.setValue({ fieldId: 'state', value: order.shipping_address.province });
subrec.setValue({ fieldId: 'zip', value: order.shipping_address.zip });
subrec.setValue({ fieldId: 'addressee', value: order.shipping_address.first_name });

subrec.setValue({ fieldId: 'attention', value: order.shipping_address.first_name });


salesOrder.selectNewLine({
    sublistId: 'item'
});


var items = order.line_items; // this list of items are in array and all are new items, dos not exist in current netsuite

items.forEach(function (item) {
var internalID = createChildItems(item.name) // getting item internal ID here
    salesOrder.setCurrentSublistValue({
        sublistId: 'item',
        fieldId: 'item',
        value:  internalID // item.id.toString() // also tried without toString(), and tried with value of existing item
    });

    salesOrder.setCurrentSublistValue({
        sublistId: 'item',
        fieldId: 'quantity',
        value: item.quantity
    });
    salesOrder.setCurrentSublistValue({
        sublistId: 'item',
        fieldId: 'price',
        value: item.price
    });

    salesOrder.setCurrentSublistValue({
        sublistId: 'item',
        fieldId: 'rate',
        value: item.price
    });

    salesOrder.commitLine({
        sublistId: 'item'
    });
});

var id = salesOrder.save({
    ignoreMandatoryFields: false
});
```

do I have to create these items before creating sales order.

Answer (score 1):

NetSuite will not automatically create a new Item record for you. You would need to first create the appropriate Item record, then use the Internal ID of the newly created Item record as the value for the `item` column of the `item` sublist.

Comment: same error, I have updated the code as per your suggestion, please review the updated code in question